# If $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are exterior bisectors then $D,E,F$ are collinear

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and AD the exterior bisector of $\angle A$, $BE$ the exterior bisector of $\angle B$, $CF$ the exterior bisector of $\angle C$ where $D\in BC$, $E\in AC$, $F\in AB$.

Show that $D,E,F$ collinear.

Comment: Pairwise $(AD,BE,CF)$ form a triangle,whose vertices cannot be collinear. I vote to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  no such theorem exists.

Comment: @Narasimham I found this exercise in many books as application to Menelaus Theorem.

Comment: Such a figure for special case of  an equilateral triangle is another equilateral triangle whose vertices are never in a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AD \cap BE = X, BE \cap CF = Y, CF \cap AD = Z$. Then obviously $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle XYZ$ are perspective centrally. This means that lines connecting coresponding vertices are passing through one point. To prove this use the fact that $CX, BZ, AY$ are altitudes in $\triangle XYZ$, so these lines meet at the orthocenter of $\triangle XYZ$.

Finally by using the Desargues's Theorem we have that $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle XYZ$ are perspective axially. Meaning that the intersection $AC \cap XY$, $BC \cap ZX$, $AB \cap ZY$ are colinear. But these are exactly the points $D,E,F$. Hence the proof.

Comment: On the first line are intersections?

Comment: @Problemsolving Yeah. obviously. I just mixed the \cap and \cup signs

Answer (score 1):

This follows immediately from trigonometric form of [Menelaus' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem). Curiously, I cannot find a link to this form, although [Cut-the-Knot notes the counterpart for Ceva's theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml). For the sake of posterity, I'll state the result, and then I'll (over-)describe its application to the problem.

> Given $\triangle ABC$, points $D$, $E$, $F$ on respective side-lines opposite $A$, $B$, $C$ are collinear if and only if
>   $$\frac{\sin\angle BAD}{\sin\angle DAC}\;\frac{\sin\angle CBE}{\sin\angle EBA}\;\frac{\sin\angle ACF}{\sin\angle FCB}= -1 \tag{$\star$}$$
>   (Clear the fractions if any of the denominators would be zero.)

The ordering of points in the angle names is important, as it conveys the *orientation* of the angle. We attach a "$+$" to a factor of $(\star)$ if the component angles are *identically* oriented, and a "$-$" if the angles are *oppositely* oriented. (This is consistent with the treatment of segment orientation in the traditional form Menelaus' theorem.)

---

For the exterior angle bisector configuration, recall that an exterior angle bisector (say, $\overline{AD}$) is perpendicular to its respective internal angle bisector (say, $\overline{AD^\prime}$).

[image]

In the figure (which is not to scale, because accurate exterior angle bisectors make for exceedingly-wide images), we have
$$\sin\angle BAD = \sin\left(90^\circ - A/2\right) = \cos\left(A/2\right) =  \sin\left(90^\circ + A/2\right) = \sin\angle DAC$$
As $\angle BAD$ and $\angle DAC$ are *oppositely* oriented, they earn a "$-$" for the corresponding Menelaean ratio, which consequently reduces to $-1$. (Note: Had $D$ appeared "on the other side" of $\overline{BC}$, then these angles would have exchanged measures while retaining their opposite-orientedness, still yielding a ratio of $-1$.)

Likewise, the angles at vertices $B$ and $C$ contribute ratios of $-1$. The reader may verify that $(-1)(-1)(-1)$ is indeed $-1$, so that $(\star)$ is satisfied. We conclude that $D$, $E$, $F$ are collinear. $\square$